# is it okay to access model from view in MVC concept?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

As along as I know, if the view want to access model, it needs to pass the controller in MVC concept.

And I wrote like the code below

```
@php
    $topik_speaker = App\TopikSpeaker::with('get_topik')->where('id_pembicara',$e->id)->get();
@endphp
@foreach ($topik_speaker as $k)
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-sm badge-primary" style="background-color: #51b3f9">{{ $k->get_topik['topik'] }}</span>
@endforeach
```

Is it breaking the rule of MVC concept or not ?

Comment: No, I think it is a bad idea to access the model directly through the view part.

Comment: Database queries should definitely not be a part of view. Database queries and other data manipulation operations should be carried out in Controller methods and variables containing data required for display should be passed to view from the controller. As far as possible views should only be responsible to display data.

Answer (score 1):

You should return data from model or db in your controller like:

```
public function show()
    {
        $data = User::all();

        return view('yourview')->with('data', $data);
    }
```

In view you get this by accessing like:

```
@foreach($data as $user)
   {{ $user->name }}
@endforeach
```